# How do I list only the numbers that have '3' in them from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

The exercise says that I have to use a loop to check the array for numbers that contain the number '3'. The program must keep looping until all the numbers are listed. Currently it wont stop looping.

The exercise hints at making the numbers in array into a string. And also hints at the use of .indexOf() method.

```
var some_array = [12, 23, 45, 36, 300, 55, 66, 78];

var number_as_string = "" + some_array;

while (number_as_string.indexOf("3"))
{

  process.stdout.write ("\n  " + number_as_string);

}

process.exit();
```

The expected result is to list the numbers: 23, 36 and 300.

Comment: You need to update `number_as_string` or the condition will never fail.

Comment: Change your loop to be a for loop.

Comment: @StevenB. in which part? loop or variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code won't convert your array od numbers into array of string. Instead it will convert the whole array into string

```
var number_as_string = "" + some_array;
```

This will output value as

```
"12,23,45,36,300,55,66,78"
```

and secondly, the while loop has not any termination condition that's why it is going into an infinite loop as indexOf will return some value always.

This code might help:

```
var some_array = [12, 23, 45, 36, 300, 55, 66, 78];     
for (let num of some_array){
    let num_in_string = num.toString()
    if (num_in_string.indexOf("3") !== -1){
        console.log(num_in_string)    
    }
}
process.exit();
```

Here I am looping through the array and getting each number in num variable as a number.
Then I am converting the number into a string using .toString() method.

The indexOf() method return either the index if present in the string or -1 is not found.
Thus the if block executes only if the returned value from indexOf is not -1 that means the "3" is present in the number and simply outputting it to console.

In case you are not familiar with toString() method, here is an alternative:

```
var some_array = [12, 23, 45, 36, 300, 55, 66, 78];     
    for (let num of some_array){
        let num_in_string = num + ""
        if (num_in_string.indexOf("3") !== -1){
            console.log(num_in_string)    
        }
    }
    process.exit();
```

Comment: There is an unexpected token error at:

```
 let num_in_string = num + "" 

```

Comment: There are no double backticks `` in code. You can remove it. Copying it from StackOverflow might have caused this.

Comment: No it's without the backticks. Backticks is just me trying to make it appear as a code in the comment.

Comment: Backticks are not used to comment on things in javascript. They are string literals.

Comment: I meant to display that as code here in stackoverflow

Comment: Oops...Maybe it's because of let keyword if you are using older javascript. Try to replace **let** with **var**. Or try an online compiler like [this](https://playcode.io/) and remove the last line `process.exit()` from the online compiler

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. I understand the code. Lastly, is the result possible without the 'for of' loop? i.e just for loop?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Use this `for(var i = 0; i < some_array.length; i++)` and then inside the for loop, get each element using i variable: `var num = some_array[i]`

Answer (score 3):

You could change your loop to a `for` loop, as below.

```
var some_array = [12, 23, 45, 36, 300, 55, 66, 78];
var result = [];
const numToLookFor = "3";

for(var i = 0; i > some_array.length; i++) {
    var num = some_array =
    if (num.toString().includes(numToLookFor)) {
        result.push(some_array[i]);
    }
}
```

You could also use an `array.filter()` method to achieve the same result.

```
var some_array = [12, 23, 45, 36, 300, 55, 66, 78];
const numToLookFor = "3";

var result = some_array.filter(num => num.toString().includes(numToLookFor));
```

Comment: I don't feel that `.indexOf()` is of any use here. By iterating over the list, you have access to each number. If I were to use `.indexOf()`, I'd be forcing it in for the sake of it. Sorry I can't help further.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var some_array = [12, 23, 45, 36, 300, 55, 66, 78];

var number_as_string = "" + some_array;

some_array.forEach(element => {
  if (element.toString().includes("3")) {
      console.log(element);
  }
});
```

or

```
const ELEMENT_TRHEE = "3";

number_as_string.split(",").forEach(element => {
   if (element.indexOf(ELEMENT_TRHEE) > -1) {
      console.log(element);
   }
});
```

Comment: The code works but I am new to JS so I don't know what .forEach will do or .toString(). I am only supposed to use .indexOf and a loop in the exercise.